# Is this possible to paginate laravel with condition?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I want to have pagination in single post page, datas comes from "contents" table. But i want to have pagination when catch spesific word (Section)  as a title go to next page in same post. 
Is this possible to make it with Laravel 5.4 .

**Example :**

> Section 1 ( this is title)
>
> text text text text text text
>
> ( **next page >** I want to add next page and it will go Section 2 page)
>
> Section 2
>
> text text text text text text
>   ( **next page >**)

my Post.php

```
 public function contents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Content::class);
}
```

blade view :

```
@if($post->contents)
          @foreach ($post->contents as $content)
                    @if ($content->type == "header")
                    <h4>{{ $content->body }}</h4>
                    @endif

                    @if ($content->type == "text")
                    <p>{{ $content->body }}</p>
                    @endif
          @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: So basically, you want a variable page size based on the data of your models? I don't think that is possible, pagination is done at query time so changing the values later will mess up the pagination data.

Comment: I want to add sections for single post, because text lenght will be too long for single page.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination use `paginate()` inside your model.

```
public function contents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Content::class)->paginate(1);
}
```

**View file**

```
@if($post->contents)
    @foreach ($post->contents() as $content)
        @if ($content->type == "header")
            <h4>{{ $content->body }}</h4>
        @endif
        @if ($content->type == "text")
            <p>{{ $content->body }}</p>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    {{ $post->contents()->links() }}
@endif
```